# Difference between Temp Table and Table Variable In SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can somebody explain me the difference between Temp table and table variable in SQL server 2005?

Comment: please try a search....there are numerous articles out there...

Comment: Thanks.. I ve searched and got lot of answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597309/what-is-the-difference-between-temporary-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few differences you can check them [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx). There is a performance difference that favors table variables because temporary tables prevent precompilation of procedures. Also the scope of a table variable is the same as the scope of variables compared to temporary tables which have bigger lifespan. In general table variables are the better choice in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these helps:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

fundamentally, temp table is written to disk until you call drop table and table variable lives in memory for the scope of the query.

Table variable is often said to be fast, **but** as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981202/unexpected-temp-table-performance)  question of my highlight, this can be a complex subject.

Comment: This is a myth. [See my answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/) on SQL Server Central detailing the differences and limitations of each.